# Trying to add points to a base R plot

Tags: r

I am trying to create an illustrative graphic. The code I have is:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(0,0,xlim=c(0,28),ylim=c(0,1),
     xaxt="n",yaxt="n",bty="n",xlab="",ylab="",type="n")
i <- 1
for(j in 1:20)
{
  test <- (6+j):26
  train <- (1+j):(5+j)
  arrows(0,1-j/20,27,1-j/20,0.05)
  points(train,rep(1-j/20,length(train)),pch=19,col="blue")
  if(length(test) >= i)
    points(test[i], 1-j/20, pch=19, col="red")
  if(length(test) >= i)
    points(test[-i], rep(1-j/20,length(test)-1), pch=19, col="gray")
  else
    points(test, rep(1-j/20,length(test)), pch=19, col="gray")
}
text(28,.95,"time")
```

What I am missing is adding "darkgrey" points before the "blue" dots to indicate that these points no longer exist or are past data.

- The blue dots indicate some data
- The red dots indicate some testing data
- The grey dots indicate some future data/test data

I want to add darkgrey dots to indicate past data at the moment I can just get "empty" places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you have done for the blue color but defining x values for points starting at 0 up to "train". So, I add three lines in your `loop` to calculate x and repeat y positions (before "train") and draw points accordingly:

```r
plot(0,0,xlim=c(0,28),ylim=c(0,1),
     xaxt="n",yaxt="n",bty="n",xlab="",ylab="",type="n")
i <- 1
j = 1 
for(j in 1:20)
{
  test <- (6+j):26
  train <- (1+j):(5+j)
  arrows(0,1-j/20,27,1-j/20,0.05)

  x_dark <- seq(0,min(train)-1, by  = 1)
  y_dark <- rep(1-j/20,length(x_dark))
  points(x_dark,y_dark,pch = 19,col = "black")

  points(train,rep(1-j/20,length(train)),pch=19,col="blue")
  if(length(test) >= i)
    points(test[i], 1-j/20, pch=19, col="red")
  if(length(test) >= i)
    points(test[-i], rep(1-j/20,length(test)-1), pch=19, col="gray")
  else
    points(test, rep(1-j/20,length(test)), pch=19, col="gray")
}
text(28,.95,"time")
```

[image]

Does it look what you are looking for ?